# Does the StringObject.reserve() function prevent memory fragmentation/leaks?

Tags: serial, string, sram, memory

I'm currently writing and testing a professional Arduino application, I'm aware of the dangers of using the String class, so I began to implement C-style strings in some places, but it's just way harder using them to receive data from a Software Serial port that's variable in size and needs some manipulation.

I've upgraded from an Arduino Uno to a Leonardo so my current minimum SRAM usage is 1325 bytes (51%)

Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
String serialContents;
char emailChar[SIZEOF_ARRAY][SIZEOF_CHAR];

void setup(){ 
  serialContents.reserve(70);
  SerialOne.begin(9600);
}

void loop{

  if (SerialOne.available() > 0) //something is there to be read
  {
    serialContents = SerialOne.readStringUntil('\n'); //make a string of the characters coming on serial
  }

  if (serialContents.length() >= 60)
  {
   serialContents = ""; //ignore serial data
  }
 else{
  serialContents = cutString(serialContents); //some String manipulation, no adding only cutting
  serialContents.replace("@", "%40");   
  serialContents.toCharArray(emailChar[count], 31); 
  serialContents = ""; //String reset
}
```

So my question is, does something like this make my code unstable? Does the 
*reserve()* function help at all?

Edit: Here's the cutString() function

```
String cutString(String request) {

  int points = request.indexOf(':');

  if (request.substring(0, points) == "CHECKOUT")
  {
    modoPedido[count] = 'o'; //char array
  }
  else if (request.substring(0, points) == "CHECKIN")
  {
    modoPedido[count] = 'i';
  }

  request = request.substring(points + 1);

  return request;
}
```

Comment: there is readBytesUntil if you want a convenient function for c-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reserving space will *help* reduce memory fragmentation, but much of what else you are doing is swamping that small improvement you have made.

The biggest area of concern is your `cutString` function, which you have omitted from your code above.  Passing a `String` as a parameter, modifying it, and then returning it again, ends up in new `String` objects being created and destroyed multiple times, which will make a mess of your heap.

Instead you should pass a String object by reference, and modify that object in-place. No need to return anything.

```
void cutString(String &theString) {
    // Modify theString here.
}
```

Of course, what you do in `cutString` could cause more problems - you should include that function in your code above so we can check it out.

Comment: Thanks!

 I've updated the first post. Damn, I think I'm creating at least three more String objects with the `substring()` function. I guess I'll use other way to see if the string contains `checkin` or `checkout` like `indexOf()`, and use the reference method instead of returning the String object.